# How to print text to file inside the awk command?

Tags: linux, email, awk, server

I have a file containing information of users of a server: First name, last name, username, grade.

I have to send an email to each user containing this information, for example:

Dear First name, Last name!

Your grade from 'class' is 'grade.

If the grade is below 5: We are waiting for you at the next exam date.

Also, I have to print these messages into one file, including the system time.

I was able to generate these messages and put them together in one file. But how can I send each different email to the corresponding users?

The method which I am trying is printing the message in a file (whish I reuse again at each user), and then add the content to the main textfile.

But I get a message error at the second case:

```
awk: cmd. line:17:
```

This line is: Dear $1 $2! echo We are waiting for you at the next exam date from class. echo

and I don't know what should I do.

Here is my code:

```
awk -v class=$1 -v file=$2 '{   
if ($4 >= 5){      
        cat > message
        Dear $1 $2! echo Your class grade is $4. echo   
}
else {
        cat > message   
        Dear $1 $2! echo We are waiting for you at the next exam date from class. echo 
}
fi
}' $2 >$1_log
```

I can send a message with the following command:

```
mail -s "message" user
```

How can I generate these emails, send them to the users and print all of them together in one file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should create the log file you're after.  To send emails you need to have access to email addresses as well, perhaps in the same class file?  Derived from username?

```
$ awk '{print "Dear " $1 " " $2 "! Your class grade is " $4 "."
        if($4 < 5) 
           print "We are waiting for you at the next exam date from class"}}' class_file > log_file
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am currently logged in to the server and I can send a message to a user, I wrongly called it an email. Can you explain this solution please? Which file will contain all the messages and how can I send them to the corresponding users?